# JavaFX ignoring drop in drag and drop file onto TextField (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, javafx, drag-and-drop, javafx-8

I want text fields to be able to handle a drop of a file from the finder.

This seems to be ignored on Mac OS X using JavaFX 8. I can't see any problems with the code, can you?

Only "Entered!" gets printed. "Dropped!" never gets printed.

```
...
txtSource = (TextField)scene.lookup("#txtSource");
txtSource.setOnDragEntered(this::handleEnter);
txtSource.setOnDragDropped(this::handleDrop);
...

public void handleEnter(DragEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Entered!");
    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);
    event.consume();
}

public void handleDrop(DragEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Dropped!");

    Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
    boolean success = false;
    if (db.hasFiles()) {
        File f = db.getFiles().get(0);
        TextField t = (TextField)event.getAcceptingObject();
        t.setText(f.getAbsolutePath());
        success = true;
    }
    /* let the source know whether the string was successfully 
     * transferred and used */
    event.setDropCompleted(success);
    event.consume();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason not clear to me, you need to accept the transfer mode in a `dragOver` handler, not a `dragEntered` handler:

```
txtSource.setOnDragOver(this::handleEnter);
// txtSource.setOnDragEntered(this::handleEnter);
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Strange. I got my original code from tutorial examples. Is this an OS X only quirk? BTW Also my event.getAcceptingObject() should have been event.getGestureTarget() to get the text field.

Comment: No idea on other platforms: I only have a mac to test on. FWIW I would explicitly pass the text field (or make it an instance variable): `txtSource.setOnDragDropped(e -> handleDragDrop(e, txtSource));` and `private void handleDragDrop(DragEvent e, TextField t) { ... }`.